# Angular 8 - Headless Chrome running twice and failing second time

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, google-chrome-headless

Locally my test cases are running fine with Chrome, No issues. I want to run my test cases on my build server ( Microsoft Azure ).

On my server builds, test cases are running twice. I want to run them only once.

I am passing configuration as HeadlessChrome. These are my configurations.

In package.json file,

```
"test": "ng test --code-coverage --watch=false --browsers ChromeHeadless",
```

my karma.conf.js file,

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],

    // customLaunchers: {
    //   'ChromeHeadless_Sandbox': {
    //       base: 'ChromeHeadless',
    //       flags: [

    //           '--no-sandbox',

    //       ],
    //      debug: true
    //   },
    // },

    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'), reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    autoWatch: false,
    concurrency: Infinity,
    singleRun: true, // Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
  });
};
```

Error:

[image]

There is a total of 131 test cases. 8 are skipped and remaining pass properly. It runs the second time and it does not work. The server shows all test cases as failed.

I have been exploring all answers on StackOverflow and Github for similar problems but still, test cases are running twice. Both times it is running for HeadlessChrome which is fine but it should run once and exit.

PS - There is also some commented code on which I am testing and trying different ways.

Please help. Where did I go wrong? How can I make test cases running only once?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

The issue was multiple projects inside the angular.json file.

I had three projects mentioned inside "projects" of angular.json. One was my app, the other one is "app-e2e" and the third one was the external project. When you run Karma, it runs the test case files in all three projects.

For the last external project, there was karma config but there were no test cases so that's why it was failing.

As for me, this third project was not required, so I removed it from angular.json and deleted it, and then Karma test cases did run successfully.

Comment: If removing the project from angular.json is not an option (I had a test/sample project for a library that had no unit tests, but was needed in the angular.json) you can either run `ng test project-name --watch=false` to run a specific project or remove the test configuration from the project without tests. I haven't tested the latter but that should work as well.